# how to do a multithreaded text search using background worker and display the entire line in a listview in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

So, I have a win form where I have to search for a string in a text file and display the line number and the entire line if I found the string. The search has to be multithreaded and all the line numbers and the lines must be on a listview. For example if the word "language" is in line number 60 , the listview must display:

60              "the line has the word language"

I have used the background worker in this regard but I am not being able to display the correct line number and the lines. Firstly, one line is being displayed multiple times and secondly, the line number is always coming to be 0. However, when I output the result in Console, the result is correct. I think I am making some error in putting the result into the listview. 
Here' s my main form.cs

```
                      public partial class Form1 : Form
          {
             public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  //  private bool start_cancel;

    bool bln = true;

    private void StartCancelbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bln)
            text2();
        else
            text1();

        bln = !bln;
    }


    private void text1()
    {
        StartCancelbtn.Text = "Start";
        this.backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();


    }

    private void text2()
    {

        StartCancelbtn.Text = "Cancel";
        StartThread();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker;
        worker = (System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)sender;

        // Get the Words object and call the main method.  
        main_work WC = (main_work)e.Argument;
        WC.CountWords(worker, e);
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
           // break;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        main_work.ReportState state =
   (main_work.ReportState)e.UserState;
        ListViewItem l1 = new ListViewItem();
                 l1.Text = state.LinesCounted.ToString();
        l1.SubItems.Add(state.line);
                   listView1.Items.Add(l1);
      }

      private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,     

      RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       {
        if (e.Error != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            MessageBox.Show("Word counting canceled.");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Finished counting words.");

    }

    private void StartThread()
    {
        main_work WC  = new main_work();
        WC.CompareString = this.searchtext.Text;
        WC.SourceFile = this.filenametextbox.Text;

        // Start the asynchronous operation.  
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(WC);

    }

    private void browsebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog brw = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (brw.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(brw.FileName))
                {
                    filenametextbox.Text = brw.FileName.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
        }
    }
```

Here is my main_work class where the actual comparison is happening:

```
       class main_work
       {
    public class ReportState

    {
       public int LinesCounted;
      public  string line;
    }
    Queue q = new Queue();
    public string SourceFile;
    public string CompareString;
    public string line2 ;
    public int linenumber=0;
    public int linenumber1 = 0;

    int LinesCounted1;
    //      public string line2;

    public void CountWords(
        System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker,
        System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the variables.  
        ReportState state = new ReportState();
        string line1 = "";
        int elapsedTime = 1;
        DateTime lastReportDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (CompareString == null ||
            CompareString == System.String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a string to be searched");
        }

        else
        {
            // Open a new stream.  
            using (System.IO.StreamReader myStream = new    System.IO.StreamReader(SourceFile))
            {
                // Process lines while there are lines remaining in the file.  
                while (!myStream.EndOfStream)
                {
                    if (worker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        // break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line1 = myStream.ReadLine();
                        line2 = (CountInString(line1, CompareString));
                        LinesCounted1 = (linenumbercount(line1, CompareString, linenumber1));

                                              //    Raise an event so the form can monitor progress.
                        int compare = DateTime.Compare(
                        DateTime.Now, lastReportDateTime.AddSeconds(elapsedTime));
                        if (compare > 0)
                        {
                            state.LinesCounted = LinesCounted1;
                            state.line = line2;
                            worker.ReportProgress(0, state);
                            lastReportDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        }

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

                    }
                }

                // Report the final count values.
                   state.LinesCounted = LinesCounted1;
                 state.line = line1;
                worker.ReportProgress(0, state);
                lastReportDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            }
        }
    }
    private string CountInString(
   string SourceString,
   string CompareString)
    {

                  if (SourceString.Contains(CompareString))
        {
                             line2 = SourceString;
            Console.WriteLine(SourceString);

        }
        return line2;


    }

    private int linenumbercount(
   string SourceString,
   string CompareString,
   int linenumber)
    {
       // Lines = 0;
        if (SourceString == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (SourceString.Contains(CompareString))
        {
                           Console.WriteLine(linenumber);

        }

         linenumber++;
           return linenumber;



              }
            }
```

Any feedback will be helpful. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and where is it that I am making a mistake as I am new to background worker and multithreading. Thanks.

Comment: 2 problems here, one there is too much code, however the main problem is its unformatted. Its annoying and its hard to read, why would anyone try to dig through this to help you? This was just a friendly tip

Comment: I was going t say that there's too much code too. You need to work a bit harder to narrow down the issue before posting. I'll wager that you haven't actually debugged the code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through it. That is a must before posting here.

Comment: Why not just use Tasks? Feels like a Homework question...